# form validation dynamic created not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have some fields (created dynamically) in a page and I am trying to each element on form submit .Bellow code is sample ,only **txtAge** field validate, **txtName** not validating .Is there any option to validate each field with bellow code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <script>
        function txtName_FormValidation() {
            document.getElementById('entryForm').onsubmit = function (e) {
                if (document.getElementById('txtName').value.length <= 0) {
                    alert(1)
                    document.getElementById('span_txtName').innerHTML = 'Please Enter Name.'
                    return false;
                };
            }
        }
        function txtAge_FormValidation() {
            document.getElementById('entryForm').onsubmit = function (e) {
                if (document.getElementById('txtAge').value.length <= 0) {
                    alert(2)
                    document.getElementById('span_txtAge').innerHTML = 'Please Enter Age.'
                    return false;
                };
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="txtName_FormValidation(); txtAge_FormValidation()">
    <form id="entryForm">
        <input type="text" id="txtName" />
        <span id="span_txtName"></span>
        <br />
        <input type="text" id="txtAge" />
        <span id="span_txtAge"></span>
        <br />
        <button type="submit" value="Sebmit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try calling your functions in your form tag on submit like this: `<form id="entryForm" onsubmit="txtName_FormValidation(); txtAge_FormValidation()">` instead of calling them on load in the body tag

Comment: Unfortunately not working

Comment: Just noticed now, if you just want to check if user introduced any value on the input, why not using `required` in each input? It will prevent from submit unless you have a value on each input

Comment: @Nitesh answer is also good, but normally is for more complex validations (like checking age superior to some value).. if you just want to check if the user introduced something on the input, just use `required` and you won't be writing unnecessary code.. but it's your call :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are replacing the first onsubmit event, for this reason only dispatch the second function.

You can try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
            document.getElementById('entryForm').onsubmit = function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                if (document.getElementById('txtName').value.length <= 0) {
                    alert(1)
                    document.getElementById('span_txtName').innerHTML = 'Please Enter Name.'
                };
                if (document.getElementById('txtAge').value.length <= 0) {
                    alert(2)
                    document.getElementById('span_txtAge').innerHTML = 'Please Enter Age.'
                };
            }
        }, false);

    </script>
</head>
<body >
    <form id="entryForm">
        <input type="text" id="txtName" />
        <span id="span_txtName"></span>
        <br />
        <input type="text" id="txtAge" />
        <span id="span_txtAge"></span>
        <br />
        <button type="submit" value="Sebmit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do like this?

calling all validations from same function?

```
<script>

    document.getElementById('entryForm').onsubmit = function(e){
            txtName_FormValidation(e);
            txtAge_FormValidation(e);
    }

        function txtName_FormValidation(e) {
                if (document.getElementById('txtName').value.length <= 0) {
                    alert(1)
                    document.getElementById('span_txtName').innerHTML = 'Please Enter Name.'
                    return false;
                };
        }
        function txtAge_FormValidation(e) {
                if (document.getElementById('txtAge').value.length <= 0) {
                    alert(2)
                    document.getElementById('span_txtAge').innerHTML = 'Please Enter Age.'
                    return false;
                };
        }
    </script>
```